# how to set checkbox value from entityFramework list

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have to set checkbox Checked or Unchecked based on value from List which I'm getting from Entity framework:

Here is my code but they are not working giving me error "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement"

```
foreach (var item in leader)
{
item.IsTopLeader == true ? chkIsTopLeader.Checked = true : chkIsTopLeader.Checked = false;
item.IsSubLeader == true ? chkIsSubLeader.Checked = true : chkIsSubLeader.Checked = false;
item.IsTeacher == true ? chkIsTeacher.Checked = true : chkIsTeacher.Checked = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can shorten your code with:

```
foreach (var item in leader)
{
   chkIsTopLeader.Checked = item.IsTopLeader;
   chkIsSubLeader.Checked = item.IsSubLeader;
   chkIsTeacher.Checked = item.IsTeacher;
}
```

You are getting the error because your ternary operator needs to assign something - i.e.:

```
bool someString = (1 == 1) ? "yes" : "no";
```

Comment: awesome, its worked but I have convert the item.IsTopLeader to boolean (chkIsTopLeader.checked=Convert.ToBoolean(item.isTopLeader) why Do I have to convert it? they are already bool properties

Comment: You don't have to convert it if it's already a boolean.  Is it a nullable boolean (bool?) maybe?

Comment: Yes they are nullable (public Nullable<bool> IsTopLeader { get; set; }) is that make any difference

Comment: you can do `chkIsTopLeader.Checked = (bool)item.IsTopLeader;`

Comment: `Nullable<bool>` can be `true`, `false`, or `null`. `Convert.ToBoolean()` converts `null` to `false`, and this may not be what you want if false and null do not mean the same thing in your application. @Jonesy: If `item.IsTopLeader` is `null`, that will result in an `InvalidOperationException`.